# IBOutlets not connecting for nested classes in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uistoryboard, iboutlet

I have an app which I want to convert it to use Swift in future. This is how I tried to achieve namespaces like structure as shown below. The class name autocomplete is not coming when I want to set class name for view controller in storyboard. Also I'm not able to easily connect the IBOutlets. I've to open assistant editor and then connect. Also I've manually enter the class name. The class field doesn't show all the available classes for a viewcontroller.

Can you please suggest a good solution by keeping the namespace structure as is?

**MyApp.swift**

```
struct MyApp {

    struct Views {

    }

    struct ViewControllers {

    }

    struct WebServices {

    }

    struct Utils {

    }

    struct Push {

    }
}
```

**Login.swift**

```
extension MyApp.ViewControllers
{
    class Login: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin : UIButton?

        @IBAction func btnLoginTapped (sender : UIButton)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are deliberately making your own developer life harder and then are surprised if it no longer works as expected? Is there *any* reason for that horrific struct nesting?

Comment: The structs are horrific for me too because swift is horrific. It doesn't support namespaces within a module. It considers the whole project as a module.

Comment: Can you tell me an easy or better way to separate the classes based on their purpose apart from creating a folder structure? Also I don't want Objective-C style class name prefix and suffixes. Otherwise I'd better drop Swift and go back to Objective-C.

Comment: Swift is awesome! It does not have namespaces - so what? Give your classes meaningful names and all the problems go away. Apart from that: no, no other advise except for *"doing fishy things in any program language is very prone to IDE or even compiler problems"*.

Comment: This is really out of the box!

Comment: Love it when people call what they don't use "horrific". What's horrific is the lack of fine grained package access control.